# Translate "loyal animal" into classical Latin

Tags: classical-latin, translation-check

I am translating the short phrase "loyal animal", or "faithful animal" into classical Latin. In this case, "animal" is intentionally very broad - I don't want to limit it to just domesticated animals or wild beasts; it can literally be any animal. My current translation is the singular *Animal Fidelis*, but I wasn't 100% positive because of the difference in gender of both words.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, if you want these two words, the correct agreement is *animal fidele* for the neuter gender.